# Tangent space $T_q(df(M))$ as a subspace of $T_q(T^*M)$

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds, tangent-spaces, co-tangent-space

I have been asked to describe the tangents space $T_q(df(M))$ as a subspace of $T_q(T^*M)$ where $f\in C^\infty(M)$ and $df$ is a 1-form (or smooth section of $T^*M$).

Here, $df:M\rightarrow T^*M$ is a function and $df(M)$ is an image of $M$ under $df$. And this image is naturally a smooth manifold because $df$ is smooth embedding.

But I have no idea on it. What should I focus on to describe it? Even it is difficult to see why $df(M)$ is a smooth manifold. I will be very appreciate for any help. Thanks in advance.

**Newly Added**

I started to think how $T_q(T^*M)$  look like. Suppose that the dimension of $M$ is $n$.

Note that $\exists $ a chart $(U,\varphi=\{x^1,\dots, x^n\})$ such that $q=(p,v)\in T^*U$. Then we have $$v=\sum_{i=1}^{n}y^idx^i. $$

Thus, we can describe local coordinate function of $(p,v)$ as $(x^1,\dots,x^n,y^1,\dots, y^n)$. It implies that our basis of $T_p(T^*M)$ would be  $$\left\{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^1},\dots ,\frac{\partial}{\partial x^n} ,\frac{\partial}{\partial y^1},\dots ,\frac{\partial}{\partial y^n}   \right\}   .$$

I think I can use this to describe $T_q(df(M))$. Currently my concern is that the dimension of $df(M)$ is $n$ since it is diffeomorphic to $M$. In other words, we should pick $n$ element that would be linear combination of the basis above.  But I am still working on.

**Added(12/5/2018)**

Now, consider $T_qL=T_q(df(M))$. Let $q=(p,df(p))\in df(M)$. And note that $df(p)\in T^*M$ which means that 
\begin{align*}
df(p)=\sum_{i=1}^n y^i dx^i
\end{align*}
where 
\begin{align*}
y^i = df(p)\left(   \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i }  \right)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}\bigg|_{p}.
\end{align*}

Observe that each $y^i$ is determined by $x^i$. In other words, each $y^i$ is a function of $x^i$. Therefore, $\forall p\in M$, we can represent $(p,df(p))$  as $(x^1,\dots, x^n)$. Thus, our basis for $T_qL$ would be
\begin{align*}
\left\{ \frac{\partial}{\partial x^1},\dots,\frac{\partial}{\partial x^n}\right\}.
\end{align*}

Thus, $T_qL$ is a set of linear combination of the basis above.

But I am uncertain about it. I am trying to making sure if it is right.

Comment: Can you say what $df(M)$ is meant to denote?

Comment: @JohnHughes  $df:M\rightarrow T^*M$  is defined by $$df(p)=(p,v)$$ where $v\in T_p^*M$. So, basically $df$ is a smooth function and $df(M)$ is the image of $M$ under $df$.

Comment: No, i guess $df(p)=(p,df_p)\in T^*M$, where $df_p\in T^*_pM$ is the differential at $p$

Comment: @PedroTamaroff  I just meant $$df(p)=(p,v) $$ since $$T^*M=\coprod_{p\in M}T^*_pM$$

Comment: My advice is to consider the map $F=df:M\to T^*M$ and try to compute its differential $dF$

Comment: @Federico Isn't $ddf=0$?

Comment: Hmm... No, I think we are making some confusion. That thing has to do with the exterior derivative. In our case, $dF$ will be related to the second derivatives of $f$ I imagine

Comment: @Federico  Oh!  but my $df$ is exterior derivative. Could you let me know how to take a derivative of $df$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $(U,\varphi=\{x^i\})$ be the local chart where $p\in U$ and $q=(p,v)\in T^*U$. Then $$ df = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i} dx^i.$$

Then we have the local coordinate $\left\{ x^i,y^i=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i} \right\}$ of $T^*M$. Then

$$T_qL=span\left\{ \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} + \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^i\partial x^k} \frac{\partial}{\partial y^k}  \right\}_{i=1}^{n}. $$

In order to understand, think about easy example when $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.  If we look at the graph of $f$, for given $p\in \mathbb{R}$, the graph of tangent line at $p$, $$y=f'(p)(x-p)+f(p) $$ is $span\left\{ \overrightarrow{e_1}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\overrightarrow{e_2}  \right\}$ where $\{e_1,e_2\}$ is a standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$.